# Iterate through LINQ Results List

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I would like to query the DB and get a list of Categories(which I am doing using Linq query syntax). Then iterate through that list of Categories for use in my C# code. This seems like it should be relatively easy but so far I'm just finding examples of displaying the results in the view. How do I use the results in the code?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried? Or maybe some pseudocode that displays what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply use a [`foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx):

```
foreach(var category in categories)
{
    // do something with it
}
```

If you want to persist it in an in-memory collection to access it by index you can create an array or list via `Enumerable.ToArray` or `Enumerable.ToList`, for example:

```
List<Category> categoryList = categories.ToList();
```

Now you can also modify it.

```
categoryList[index] = otherCategory;
```

or you can use a `for`-loop instead:

```
for(int index = 0; index < categoryList.Count; index++)
{
    Category cat = categoryList[index];
    //do something
}
```

Comment: How do I put the first result into a variable? For example if I was iterating over an array it would be: String myVar = Catigory[i]

Comment: @user800426 `string myVar = category;`

Comment: I did something very similar - iterating over the result set of a LINQ expression with a for loop, and my boss said to use LINQ in the original expression instead of a loop after the LINQ expression.

Comment: @James: i must admit that i don't understand what you've done and what your boss didn't like. Maybe you want to ask a question here which demostrates both approaches and asks why you should not use the non-boss way. You could leave a comment here then i'l have a look.

Answer (score 3):

You can also add code into the Linq queries.  For example:

```
var numbs = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

numbs.Select(i => {

    SomeMethod(i);
    return i;

});
```

Then you can also select new results or modify the results and store them into the existing array. For example

```
var numbs = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

var multList = numbs.Select(i => {

    var mult = MultiplyBy2(i);
    Console.Write("New Number: " + mult);
    return mult;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add another alternative you can also use a for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < categories.Count(); i++)
{
  var thisElement = categories.ElementAt(i);
}
```

Although a little less readable for loops are often quite a bit faster (although it depends largely on the underlying type of your IEnumerable).

Comment: You should not use this `for`-loop on the query itself. Instead you should create a collection from it. Otherwise you are executing the query on every iteration (and on `categories.Count()`). So if `categories` is a database query (and it is) you are executing it on each and every record that the query returns just to get to the element at the next index.